# How to render and cache user-specific pages?

Tags: javascript, caching, web-applications, web.py

I'm building a website on top of web.py, postgres and redis. In some views of my app, there are some user-specific information. For example, if a user logged in, the links on the top bar will be different from non-login user's view or stuff like "welcome $username". I can implement it by rendering every page in response of every request. Except the user-specif info, the other parts of some views are exactly the same. So I want to cache the rendered page. I've come up with some implementation approach, but I don't know which to use and because I'm kinda learning web development by myself, I want to know how professional web developers deal with this issue.

Here are my approaches:

- save some data in cookies and write a piece of javascript script to manipulate HTML DOM after pages arrived at user's browsers. that way, in some view of my app, all user get the exactly same page but data stored in cookies are different, then pages rendered using javascript are different
- render and cache every version of some pages for every user, but I think it's not a good idea....
- render and cache parts of pages and construct pages when a request comes in. I'm using web.py's Templetor to render pages. There is a basic site-wide template works as a wrapper now. If I use this constructing approach, instead of using a basic template, I may have to render and concatenate different parts of a page. Then cache proper fragments for every user.

What should I do? Are there better solutions? Sorry for my terrible English writing skill :(
Hope it can express what I want to ask. Any help will be appreciated and thank in advance! Thank you! :D

**EDIT:** the code contained user-specific information is like this

```
<nav>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="primary">
      <ul class="nav">
        <li><span>Home</span></li>
        <li><span>About</span></li>
        <li><span>Contact</span></li>
      </ul>
    </div>

    <div class="secondary">
      $if session.logged_in:
          <span>Welcome, $session.username</span>
          <a href="/new">new post</a>
          <a href="/logout">logout</a>
      $else:
          <a href="/register">register</a>
          <a href="/login">login</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

I'm using session now which means I can't just cache one version for every user. How does stackoverflow.com implement this? I see the information in the top bar is different when I'm not logged in and sure I know every user's view is different...

Comment: Do you mean _caching_ HTML page on the server side after rendering ?

Comment: @Febien Yes! Exactly. Cache rendered page in redis

Comment: You could take a look at [Varnish](https://www.varnish-cache.org/).

Comment: @Febien thank you. I'm checking it out. it seems is another caching software...

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that most of sites just cache the data not the final html file. That's much easier to manage and more flexible to implement. Though still have to render page on every request, but can reduce the load of database. As to not logged in users, app can choose to cache the final html page. I was keeping thinking of caching final html file. What a idiot I am....

Comment: So, how are you doing it in web.py? Can you update your answer with what you found?